# Bokeh Dynamic Axis Scaling

Tags: javascript, python, django, bokeh

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177455/bokeh-python-how-to-dynamically-set-values-for-x-axis-and-y-axis) but I have code examples. I have created a bokeh chart in a Django app that plots times swam in competitive swimming events over time, and uses one plot

```
plot = figure(
        title='Event Progress',
        x_axis_label='Date',
        y_axis_label='Time',
        x_axis_type='datetime',
        plot_width=400,
        plot_height=200,
        tools=tools,
        responsive=True,
    )
```

the `Select` widget, and a `CustomJS` function to only display one line at a time. The problem is, if one event has a time of 10 minutes and another has a time of 25 seconds, the y-axis (time) scales so that both will be seen when they are made visible. I declare each line like

```
plot_lines[event] = plot.line('x_'+event, 
                              'y_'+event, 
                              line_width=4, 
                              source=source)
```

and the `Select` widget like

```
multi_select = Select(title="Select Event:", 
                      value=events[0], 
                      options=events, 
                      callback=callback)
```

if that's helpful. I'm also custom formatting the y-axis as

```
plot.yaxis.formatter = FuncTickFormatter(code="""
    return Math.floor(tick/60) + ":" + tick.toFixed(2)
""")
```

so that it displays the time correctly. Everything else is just formatting the data, setting the lines to visible or not and the callback function. Is there a way to dynamically scale a single axis for each line? I suppose ideally I could set the y-max and y-min for each line to keep it within the chart bounds, but I'm not sure if that's possible or what my other options are.

Update: Here's my complete code.

```
def graph_event(swimmer):
hover_tool = date_time_hover_tool()
tools = ['pan', 'box_zoom', hover_tool, 'reset', 'save']
plot = figure(
    title='Event Progress',
    x_axis_label='Date',
    y_axis_label='Time',
    x_axis_type='datetime',
    plot_width=400,
    plot_height=200,
    tools=tools,
    responsive=True,
)
# format datetime.timedelta objects to MM:ss.mm
plot.yaxis.formatter = FuncTickFormatter(code=
    """
    return Math.floor(tick/60) + ":" + tick.toFixed(2)
    """
)

data_source = {}
events = []
first_event = None
for event in EVENT_CHOICE:
    e = '_'.join([word.lower() for word in event[0].split()])

    results = Event.objects.filter(swimmer=swimmer).filter(event=event[0]).order_by('date')
    if results.exists():
        if len(results) == 1: # one point will not display well on graph
            data_source['x_'+e] = None
            data_source['y_'+e] = None
            data_source['date_'+e] = None
            data_source['time_'+e] = None
            continue

        events.append(event[1])
        if first_event == None:
            first_event = e

        x, y = [], []
        date, time = [], []
        for r in results.iterator():
            d = r.date
            t = r.time.total_seconds()
            x.append(d)
            y.append(t)
            date.append(d.strftime('%m/%d/%y')) # date to string for hover
            time.append('{:d}:{:.2f}'.format(int(t)/60, t)) # time to string for hover

        data_source['x_'+e] = x
        data_source['y_'+e] = y
        data_source['date_'+e] = date
        data_source['time_'+e] = time

    else:
        # eliminates KeyError exceptions
        data_source['x_'+e] = None
        data_source['y_'+e] = None
        data_source['date_'+e] = None
        data_source['time_'+e] = None

# set initial graph
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=data_source['x_'+first_event],
    y=data_source['y_'+first_event],
    date=data_source['date_'+first_event],
    time=data_source['time_'+first_event]
))
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source)

try:
    select = Select(title="Select Event:", value=events[0], options=events)
except IndexError:
    return None, None

# callback modifies data source depending on Select box
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, select=select), code="""
        data = %s;

        if (select.value == "50 Freestyle") {
            source.data['x'] = data.x_50_free;
            source.data['y'] = data.y_50_free;
            source.data['date'] = data.date_50_free;
            source.data['time'] = data.time_50_free;
        } else if (select.value == "100 Freestyle") {
            source.data['x'] = data.x_100_free;
            source.data['y'] = data.y_100_free;
            source.data['date'] = data.date_100_free;
            source.data['time'] = data.time_100_free;
        } else if (select.value == "200 Freestyle") {
            console.log(select.value);
            source.data['x'] = data.x_200_free;
            source.data['y'] = data.y_200_free;
            source.data['date'] = data.date_200_free;
            source.data['time'] = data.time_200_free;
        } else if (select.value == "500 Freestyle") {
            source.data['x'] = data.x_500_free;
            source.data['y'] = data.y_500_free;
            source.data['date'] = data.date_500_free;
            source.data['time'] = data.time_500_free;
        } else if (select.value == "1000 Freestyle") {
            source.data['x'] = data.x_1000_free;
            source.data['y'] = data.y_1000_free;
            source.data['date'] = data.date_1000_free;
            source.data['time'] = data.time_1000_free;
        } else if (select.value == "50 Backstroke") {
            source.data['x'] = data.x_50_back;
            source.data['y'] = data.y_50_back;
            source.data['date'] = data.date_50_back;
            source.data['time'] = data.time_50_back;
        } else if (select.value == "100 Backstroke") {
            source.data['x'] = data.x_100_back;
            source.data['y'] = data.y_100_back;
            source.data['date'] = data.date_100_back;
            source.data['time'] = data.time_100_back;
        } else if (select.value == "200 Backstroke") {
            source.data['x'] = data.x_200_back;
            source.data['y'] = data.y_200_back;
            source.data['date'] = data.date_200_back;
            source.data['time'] = data.time_200_back;
        } else if (select.value == "50 Breaststroke") {
            source.data['x'] = data.x_50_breast;
            source.data['y'] = data.y_50_breast;
            source.data['date'] = data.date_50_breast;
            source.data['time'] = data.time_50_breast;
        } else if (select.value == "100 Breaststroke") {
            source.data['x'] = data.x_100_breast;
            source.data['y'] = data.y_100_breast;
            source.data['date'] = data.date_100_breast;
            source.data['time'] = data.time_100_breast;
        } else if (select.value == "200 Breaststroke") {
            source.data['x'] = data.x_200_breast;
            source.data['y'] = data.y_200_breast;
            source.data['date'] = data.date_200_breast;
            source.data['time'] = data.time_200_breast;
        } else if (select.value == "50 Butterfly") {
            source.data['x'] = data.x_50_fly;
            source.data['y'] = data.y_50_fly;
            source.data['date'] = data.date_50_fly;
            source.data['time'] = data.time_50_fly;
        } else if (select.value == "100 Butterfly") {
            source.data['x'] = data.x_100_fly;
            source.data['y'] = data.y_100_fly;
            source.data['date'] = data.date_100_fly;
            source.data['time'] = data.time_100_fly;
        } else if (select.value == "200 Butterfly") {
            source.data['x'] = data.x_200_fly;
            source.data['y'] = data.y_200_fly;
            source.data['date'] = data.date_200_fly;
            source.data['time'] = data.time_200_fly;
        } else if (select.value == "100 IM") {
            source.data['x'] = data.x_100_im;
            source.data['y'] = data.y_100_im;
            source.data['date'] = data.date_100_im;
            source.data['time'] = data.time_100_im;
        } else if (select.value == "200 IM") {
            source.data['x'] = data.x_200_im;
            source.data['y'] = data.y_200_im;
            source.data['date'] = data.date_200_im;
            source.data['time'] = data.time_200_im;
        } else if (select.value == "400 IM") {
            source.data['x'] = data.x_400_im;
            source.data['y'] = data.y_400_im;
            source.data['date'] = data.date_400_im;
            source.data['time'] = data.time_400_im;
        } else if (select.value == "Base Freestyle") {
            source.data['x'] = data.x_base_free;
            source.data['y'] = data.y_base_free;
            source.data['date'] = data.date_base_free;
            source.data['time'] = data.time_base_free;
        } else if (select.value == "Base Backstroke") {
            source.data['x'] = data.x_base_back;
            source.data['y'] = data.y_base_back;
            source.data['date'] = data.date_base_back;
            source.data['time'] = data.time_base_back;
        } else if (select.value == "Base Breaststroke") {
            source.data['x'] = data.x_base_breast;
            source.data['y'] = data.y_base_breast;
            source.data['date'] = data.date_base_breast;
            source.data['time'] = data.time_base_breast;
        } else if (select.value == "Base Butterfly") {
            source.data['x'] = data.x_base_fly;
            source.data['y'] = data.y_base_fly;
            source.data['date'] = data.date_base_fly;
            source.data['time'] = data.time_base_fly;
        } else if (select.value == "Base IM") {
            source.data['x'] = data.x_base_im;
            source.data['y'] = data.y_base_im;
            source.data['date'] = data.date_base_im;
            source.data['time'] = data.time_base_im;
        }

        source.change.emit()
""" % json.dumps(data_source, cls=DatetimeEncoder))

select.callback = callback

return components(column(select, plot, responsive=True))
```

And here's the hover tool and JSON datetime serializer.

```
class DatetimeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
"""
Encodes Python datetime.date objects to make compatible with JSON serialization.
"""
def default(self, obj):
    try:
        return super(DatetimeEncoder, obj).default(obj)
    except TypeError:
        return str(obj)

def date_time_hover_tool():
    """
    Generates the HTML for the Bokeh's hover data tool on our graph.
    """
    hover_html = """
      <div>
        <span class="hover-tooltip">@date</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="hover-tooltip">@time</span>
      </div>
    """
    return HoverTool(tooltips=hover_html)
```

Hopefully this isn't too confusing. Basically I'm looping over each event for that athlete and getting the data if it exists, then in the callback just setting the source data.

Answer (score 0):

If you only ever want to show one line at a time, then an easier solution might be to update the data for a single line. One approach is to "template" the data into directly into the callback text. I wouldn't always recommend this approach but for not-huge data sizes it can work quite well:

```
import json
from math import sin

from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, Select
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file("foo.html")

xl, yl = list(range(100)), [sin(x) for x in xl]
xs, ys = list(range(500)), [sin(x) for x in xs]
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=xl, y=yl))

plot = figure()
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source)

select = Select(title="Event:", value="long", options=["long", "short"])

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, select=select), code="""
    data = %s;
    if (select.value == "long") {
        source.data['x'] = data.xl
        source.data['y'] = data.yl
    } else {
        source.data['x'] = data.xs
        source.data['y'] = data.ys
    }
    source.change.emit()
""" % json.dumps(dict(xl=xl, yl=yl, xs=xs, ys=ys)))

select.callback = callback

show(column(select, plot))
```

If you *really* need to have separate line renderers, then the `DataRange1d` models has `.renderers` property that specifies which renderers are to be "auto-ranged" over. But it's not set to be responsive except at startup and reset. So your JS callback would need to set the `.renderers` on the range appropriately, and also call the `.reset` method on the range to have that change take effect. I *think* that would work as expected.

Comment: So that will change the y-axis scale depending on the Select value? Because if so than that's probably easier than what I was doing anyway.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The example above is complete and can be run as-is for you to evaluate how it operates in the context of your full use-case.

Comment: Sorry this is coming so late but I am having a slight issue with what you suggested. I have gotten to the point where the page loads without any problems and an initial graph is displayed, but if I use the select widget the graph and axis are wiped, like the graph is changing data sources but the visual part is not getting updated. I've updated my question with the code so hopefully you can check it out.

Comment: I know this is old, but here's to hope @bigreddot see this.  I'm curious if I have a `plot=figure(y_range=DataRange1d())` and then in a `CustomJS` callback you're saying someone should call `plot.y_range.renderers.reset()`?  Because i'm trying and getting no function reset, or should it be on just `plot.y_range.reset`?

Comment: There is a `reset` on `DataRange1d` but AFAICT it doesn't do anything relevant, at least not anymore. Also it appears `renderers` is computed on the fly now, so I would expect updating it to just work at any time.